# Cyclic computational graphs with Tensorflow or Theano

Tags: tensorflow, theano, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Both `TensorFlow` and `Theano` do not seem to support cyclic computational graphs, cyclic elements are implemented as recurrent cells with buffer and unrolling (RNN / LSTM cells), but this limitation is mostly related with the computation of back-propagation. I don't have a particular need for computing back-propagation but just the forward propagations.

Is there a way to ignore this limitation, or perhaps just to break down arbitrary computational graphs in acyclic components?

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow **does** support cyclic computation graphs. The [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop) function allows you to specify a while loop with arbitrary subgraphs for the condition and the body of the loop, and the runtime will execute the loop in parallel. The [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#scan) function is a higher-level API that is similar to Theano's [`theano.scan()`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html) function. Both allow you to loop over tensors of dynamic size.

Comment: thanks. I've added an example (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37566925/1792701) of a graph where I am trying to use the previous value of the tensor as an input, but I get that the tensor has value zero on each run, rather than preserving its previous value. Should I just replace `sess.run` with `while_loop`?