# Tensorflow,assign value to variable

Tags: tensorflow

I am total newbie to tensorflow, I am learning from

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

fixW = tf.assign(W, [-1.])
```

works fine,but

```
fixb = tf.assign(b, [1.])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 272, in assign
    return ref.assign(value)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

One other example

```
zero_tsr = tf.zeros([1.,2.])
zero_tsr
<tf.Tensor 'zeros:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>
```

If I try to change zero_tsr

```
fixz = tf.assign(zero_tsr, [2.,2.])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 272, in assign
    return ref.assign(value)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Again,the same problem.

I have not changed shell,everything is the same.Why do I have problem here?

Comment: Can you show one **complete** file that produces an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the example you posted:

```
zero_tsr = tf.zeros([1.,2.])
zero_tsr
<tf.Tensor 'zeros:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>
```

`zero_tsr` is a constant and not a variable, so you cannot assign a value to it.

From [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign):

> assign(
>       ref,
>       value,
>       validate_shape=None,
>       use_locking=None,
>       name=None )
>
> ref: A mutable Tensor. Should be from a Variable node. May be
>   uninitialized.

For example, this will work fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
zero_tsr = tf.Variable([0,0])
tf.assign(zero_tsr,[4,5])
```

while this code will raise an error

```
import tensorflow as tf
zero_tsr = tf.zeros([1,2])
tf.assign(zero_tsr,[4,5])
```

The error that is raised is exactly the error you posted:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

Comment: Im confused - that is not his error, nor does it have anything to do with the error OP posted, does it? (I am talking about `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'`)

Comment: @Xatenev This is the OP's error, see the example I added.

Comment: Wow that is really weird - can you elaborate (for me) on how/why that error is thrown? Error seems to imply the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Xatenev I think it is related to the discussion in the comments in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566925/preserving-tensor-values-between-session-runs. (tf.Variable has the attribute assign, while constant does not). Also, as listed in tf.assign documentation, ref should be from a Variable node. constant is not from such a node.

Comment: True - now it all makes sense. Thanks :) +1

Comment: How would I go about assigning ones to a subset of a tf.zeros tensor if I cannot use assign?